# Creating Index in Casbah Issue

Tags: mongodb

My program will do the following (using Casbah):

```
load2000DocsIntoMongo() 
def myIndexExists= collection.getIndexInfo().exists( x => x.getAs[String] 
         ("name").getOrElse("") == MY_INDEX_NAME)
if (myIndexExists) println("log exists")
else { 
  val start = System.nanoTime()
  collection.ensureIndex(MY_INDEX) 
  println( (System.nanoTime - start) / 1000000000 + "seconds to index")
}
```

When starting `mongod` from scratch, and then running my test, the index works. After running the test, I check `db.collection.getIndexes()` to see if it was created.

However, after running my test once, and then running `db.collection.drop()`, I re-ran the test. The test inserts the documents correctly, but it incorrectly reports that that index was created. I say this, because even though the *X seconds to index* was printed out, Mongo shell's `db.collection.getIndexes()` shows that it was not created.

Why isn't `collection.ensureIndex(MY_INDEX)` always creating the index if it doesn't exist?

**EDIT**

When adding an index via `collection.ensureIndex(MY_INDEX)`, Casbah called the Java library's method to create an index. In this method, a private map variable, **_createdIndexes**, was updated with this index.

When I had modified Mongo's indexes **outside** of the Java library, it did not know to update the **_createdIndexes** variable. As a result, when trying to create the same index, **_createdIndexes** already had that value, so it simply called `return;` since the library's cache, i.e. the variable, already put this index in its map.

To work around this issue, I call `collection.dropIndexes()`, which will clear the **_createdIndexes** variable.

`Casbah source` - https://github.com/mongodb/casbah/blob/master/casbah-core/src/main/scala/MongoCollection.scala

`Java source` - https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/src/main/com/mongodb/DBCollection.java

Please see [Ross](https://stackoverflow.com/users/156427/ross)'s detailed answer for the full story.

Comment: You are experiencing something too strange to debug with just that code. You are using `MY_INDEX_NAME` in your code but `MY_INDEX` in your question. Show us the second call to `ensureIndex` at the end. The Mongo shell is used more than Casbah, try to reproduce the problem there (inserting a single document is enough).

Comment: Sorry the MY_ INDEX fields are the same - typo.

Comment: This may be a Mongo bug. I emailed a software engineer who maintains Casbah. More to come once I hear from this person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not a bug per sae however, I agree this highlights an issue if you use the Casvah driver and the shell or another driver at the same time.

The underlying java code cache doesn't know what you are doing in the shell and it expects to be the only source of true (other drivers also follow this pattern).  The reason there is a cache is to aid performance, so that ensureIndex can be repeatedly called and have little performance impact.

So the question is what is the best course of action in this scenario?

1. Only use the Casbah driver to create and manage indexes - what ensureIndex relies on
2. Only use the shell to create and manage indexes - the shell doesnt cache
3. Don't trust the cache in Casbah code

You could call `createIndex` and bypass the cache altogether.  There is a jira ticket on this: [JAVA-667](http://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-667) and it looks for the next major release (3.0) the cache is being removed.